# How to set Picture in QListView

Tags: qt, nokia

i have use this code for getting pictures from Phone's memory...

```
TFileName path = PathInfo::PhoneMemoryRootPath();
path.Append( PathInfo::ImagesThumbnailPath());
```

How can i set this picture path in my listview?
Any help?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about phone programming, but in a Qt (desktop) program  you would read the image with QPixmap::load. You could then create QLabels and set their pixmaps. Or you use a QItemDelegate to display the images.